# Adding XValues to a series line graph

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble adding X Values to my Series line graph.

I have my code like this

```
Set Xacross = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(TimeNumber, 1))

Worksheets("Graph").Activate

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.XValues
        .Name = "Time"
        .Values = Xacross
    End With
```

But whenever I run the code I always get `Error 438`

I have also tried using  code like

`ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.XValues = Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(TimeNumber,1))`

As well as

```
Xacross = Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(TimeNumber,1) 
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.XValues = Xacross
```

Can you offer any solutions or locations of solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series has a `.Name`, `.XValues`, and (Y) `.Values`. Your code mixes this up.

Change this:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.XValues
    .Name = "Time"
    .Values = Xacross
End With
```

to this:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    .Name = "Time"
    .XValues = Xacross
    ' and perhaps you need to specify .Values = something?
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You either...

**- have to specify the SeriesCollection you are editing**

```
SeriesCollection(index).XValues
```

**- or have to add a new seriescollection**

```
SeriesCollection.Add source:=Xacross
```

And about locations of solutions: generally try typing the problematic object (seriescollection) into google like this:

*seriescollection vba*

On MSDN’s page you can find a lot of examples.

(Sorry for no formatting, typing from my cell)